# Python create a line plot on each type of column value in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, data-visualization

I have the following dataframe:

```
gapminder
```

[image]

It has five unique values for continent.

[image]

I need to create a plot that looks something like:

[image]

I have used `df.groupby().apply()` to apply plot function on each country of the data:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)

def plot_lines(df,x_axis,y_axis,**kwargs):
    ax.plot(df[x_axis],df[y_axis],**kwargs)

gapminder.groupby("country").apply(plot_lines,"year","lifeExp")
```

This creates this plot:

[image]

Now the problem is, how do I create a line plot on each type of continent of the data, I want to create a line plot (year vs lifeExp) on each continent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `subplots` to create subplots

You can separate dataframes based on continents and plot each separately.

Use this.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,5,figsize=(15,4))

continents = ['Asia', 'Europe', 'Africa', 'Americas', 'Oceania']
colors = ['blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'purple']
for i, details in enumerate(zip(continents, colors)):
  #details will contain list of tuples of continent and color
  ax[i].plot(gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == details[0]]['year'].tolist(), gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == details[0]]['lifeExp'].tolist(), c=details[1])
  ax[i].set_title(details[0])
```

Another easy way is this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(15,4))
plt.subplot(1,5,1)
plt.plot(gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Asia']['year'].tolist(), gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Asia']['lifeExp'].tolist(), c = 'blue')
plt.title('Asia')
plt.xlabel('Year')

plt.subplot(1,5,2)
plt.plot(gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Europe']['year'].tolist(), gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Europe']['lifeExp'].tolist(), c = 'yellow')
plt.title('Europe')
plt.xlabel('Year')

plt.subplot(1,5,3)
plt.plot(gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Africa']['year'].tolist(), gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Africa']['lifeExp'].tolist(), c = 'green')
plt.title('Africa')
plt.xlabel('Year')

plt.subplot(1,5,4)
plt.plot(gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Americas']['year'].tolist(), gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Americas']['lifeExp'].tolist(), c = 'orange')
plt.title('Americas')
plt.xlabel('Year')

plt.subplot(1,5,5)
plt.plot(gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Oceania']['year'].tolist(), gapminder[gapminder['continent'] == 'Oceania']['lifeExp'].tolist(), c = 'purple')
plt.title('Oceania')
plt.xlabel('Year')
```